# TypeORM Connection "default" was not found when using a routes file and repository pattern

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, express-router

I have a TS project where I'm using TypeORM. I'm using Repository pattern so I have layers: Controller -> Service -> Repository.

The Controller constructor initialize the Service class which initialize Repository class, where the constructor is:

```js
constructor(){
    this.ormRepository = getRepository(TypeormEntity)
}
```

This works fine when I create the routes in the `index.ts` like this:

```
createConnection().then(() => {
  const controller = new MyController()
  app.get('/', controller.getSomething);
})
```

The connection is created and then I initialize the class using `new MyController()`.

The problem is when I want to get the routes in another file. I want to get this structure folder:

```
src
 |--> index.ts
 |--> routes 
      |--> v1
           |--> router.ts
           |--> value
                 |--> value.route.ts
      |--> v2
           |--> ...
```

So, to achieve this, the `index.ts` import the routes. But the problem is, as the import is done, the `MyController()` constructor is executed and the execution fails.

So I want to have something like this in `index.ts`

```js
import * as express from 'express'
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
import Router from './routes/v1/router'

const app = express()
createConnection().then(() => {
  app.use('/', Router)
  app.listen(port)
})
```

Also, following the import call, the file `router.ts` in `routes/v1` is:

```js
import { json, Router } from 'express'
import valueRouter from './value/value.route'

const router = Router()
router.use(json())
router.use('/value', valueRouter)

export default router
```

This is to add a "prefix" to all routes depending the resource they call.

And `value.route.ts` is where the controller is initialized and fails.

```js
import { Router } from "express";
import ValueController from '../../../controller/value.controller'

const router = Router()
const vc = new ValueController()
router.get('/',vc.getSomething)

export default router
```

I've tested deleting the constructor and the project intializes ok, so the problem is the repository initialization accross Controller & Service.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my own issue using dynamic imports.

Now my `index.ts` looks like this:

```js
createConnection().then(() => {
  import('./routes/v1/router').then((router: any) => {
    app.use('/', router.default)
    app.listen(port)
  })
})
```

Which I think is much cleaner than having all routes added in this file. Calling routes in an external file I can manage a huge amount and maintain a clean structure.